# What does -(XYPoint *) origin; mean

Tags: objective-c-2.0

I am new to Objective-C and I am working hard to understand how it works. I get the basic idea with pointers, but this thing has me stumped:

```
-(XYPoint *) origin;
```

What does it mean when they add the * after the Class name inside of parenthesis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the method `origin` will return a pointer to an instance of `XYPoint`.